# Use Cusor instead of While Loop

Tags: sql

I have a While Loop that goes through about 500,000 records and is very slow. I was reading online that I maybe able to use something called a Fast Forward Cursor to speed up the performance of the query. I have looked up fast forward cursors to try to apply it to my situation. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find anything that will explain how to convert a WHILE Loop into this type of cursor in the depth I need to be able to follow along and perform the necessary changes to my code. Any suggestions or advice would be appreciated. Below is the code I am using for my While Loop as well as some sample data.

The logic takes the test data which contains multiple months in one record and using the While Loop takes each record with multiple months and creates one record per month.

```
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TEST_Data') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEST_Data

create table #TEST_Data ( 
    Number varchar(50)
    , P_Values varchar(50)
    , StartDate date
    , EndDate date
    , NumberMonths numeric(7, 0)
    , TotalAmount money
    , MonthlyAmount money
    , MultipleMonthid int
);


INSERT INTO #TEST_Data VALUES
('ABC1235', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-2066.82', '-295.26', '1')
, ('ABC1236', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '431.2', '215.6', '2')
, ('ABC1237', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '457.84', '228.92', '3')
, ('ABC1238', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-1279.4', '-255.88', '4')
, ('ABC1239', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '569.52', '47.46', '5')
, ('ABC1240', '1', '2/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '4', '-546.08', '-136.52', '6')
, ('ABC1241', '1', '1/1/2019', '4/30/2019', '4', '149.4', '37.35', '7')
, ('ABC1242', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '549.5', '109.9', '8')
, ('ABC1243', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1054.3', '210.86', '9')
, ('ABC1244', '1', '3/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '5', '2888.25', '577.65', '10')
, ('ABC1245', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '379.5', '189.75', '11')
, ('ABC1246', '1', '5/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '8', '475.68', '59.46', '12')
, ('ABC1247', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-511.55', '-102.31', '13')
, ('ABC1248', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1531.6', '218.8', '14')
, ('ABC1249', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1043.2', '208.64', '15')
, ('ABC1250', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1554.35', '222.05', '16')
, ('ABC1251', '1', '6/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '2', '356.98', '178.49', '17')
, ('ABC1252', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '356.98', '178.49', '18')
, ('ABC1253', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '6787.5', '1357.5', '19')
, ('ABC1254', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-3327.2', '-665.44', '20')
, ('ABC1255', '1', '4/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '4', '-778.44', '-194.61', '21')
, ('ABC1256', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-2061.29', '-294.47', '22')
, ('ABC1257', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '850.1', '170.02', '23')
, ('ABC1258', '1', '7/1/2018', '11/30/2018', '5', '3998.6', '799.72', '24')
, ('ABC1259', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '9.48', '0.79', '25')
, ('ABC1260', '1', '10/1/2018', '11/30/2018', '2', '728.66', '364.33', '26')
, ('ABC1261', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '4539.15', '648.45', '27')
, ('ABC1262', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-403.55', '-80.71', '28')
, ('ABC1263', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '270.45', '54.09', '29')
, ('ABC1264', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '2336.4', '194.7', '30')
, ('ABC1265', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1706.39', '243.77', '31')
, ('ABC1266', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-2055.48', '-293.64', '32')
, ('ABC1267', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1018.08', '145.44', '33')
, ('ABC1268', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-2782.08', '-397.44', '34')
, ('ABC1269', '1', '1/1/2018', '2/28/2018', '2', '-360.4', '-180.2', '35')
, ('ABC1270', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-968.66', '-138.38', '36')
, ('ABC1271', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '-188.9', '-94.45', '37')
, ('ABC1272', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '257.6', '51.52', '38')
, ('ABC1273', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1139.5', '227.9', '39')
, ('ABC1274', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-820', '-164', '40')
, ('ABC1275', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-1051.8', '-210.36', '41')
, ('ABC1276', '1', '2/1/2019', '3/31/2019', '2', '671.44', '335.72', '42')
, ('ABC1277', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1168.95', '233.79', '43')
, ('ABC1278', '1', '6/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '2', '479.5', '239.75', '44')
, ('ABC1279', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '479.5', '239.75', '45')
, ('ABC1280', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1993.67', '284.81', '46')
, ('ABC1281', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '7456.33', '1065.19', '47')
, ('ABC1282', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-1837.5', '-367.5', '48')
, ('ABC1283', '1', '6/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '2', '-312.14', '-156.07', '49')
, ('ABC1284', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '781.62', '111.66', '50')
, ('ABC1285', '1', '1/1/2018', '6/30/2018', '6', '-3995.58', '-665.93', '51')
, ('ABC1286', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1159.15', '231.83', '52')
, ('ABC1287', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-9376.25', '-1875.25', '53')
, ('ABC1288', '1', '2/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '11', '1785.08', '162.28', '54')
, ('ABC1289', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '-677.24', '-338.62', '55')
, ('ABC1290', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '8.88', '0.74', '56')
, ('ABC1291', '1', '1/1/2018', '6/30/2018', '6', '-112.92', '-18.82', '57')
, ('ABC1292', '1', '6/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '2', '462.98', '231.49', '58')
, ('ABC1293', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '-534.32', '-267.16', '59')
, ('ABC1294', '1', '2/1/2018', '3/31/2018', '2', '548.62', '274.31', '60')
, ('ABC1295', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '286.42', '143.21', '61')
, ('ABC1296', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '4907.15', '981.43', '62')
, ('ABC1297', '1', '4/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '9', '7.29', '0.81', '63')
, ('ABC1298', '1', '1/1/2019', '4/30/2019', '4', '2462.56', '615.64', '64')
, ('ABC1299', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '8042.04', '670.17', '65')
, ('ABC1300', '1', '1/1/2019', '3/31/2019', '3', '1109.91', '369.97', '66')
, ('ABC1301', '1', '4/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '9', '2642.94', '293.66', '67')
, ('ABC1302', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-1430.45', '-204.35', '68')
, ('ABC1303', '1', '2/1/2018', '3/31/2018', '2', '1285.74', '642.87', '69')
, ('ABC1304', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-1163.45', '-232.69', '70')
, ('ABC1305', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '2319.59', '331.37', '71')
, ('ABC1306', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '6464.78', '923.54', '72')
, ('ABC1307', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '4893.98', '699.14', '73')
, ('ABC1308', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-1249.35', '-249.87', '74')
, ('ABC1309', '1', '1/1/2018', '8/31/2018', '8', '2318', '289.75', '75')
, ('ABC1310', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '2123.17', '303.31', '76')
, ('ABC1311', '1', '5/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '3', '-92.55', '-30.85', '77')
, ('ABC1312', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-789.9', '-157.98', '78')
, ('ABC1313', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '4136.52', '2068.26', '79')
, ('ABC1314', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-450.59', '-64.37', '80')
, ('ABC1315', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '-570', '-285', '81')
, ('ABC1316', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '264.48', '22.04', '82')
, ('ABC1317', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1834.77', '262.11', '83')
, ('ABC1318', '1', '5/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '3', '1194.72', '398.24', '84')
, ('ABC1319', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-2398.27', '-342.61', '85')
, ('ABC1320', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '2596.44', '216.37', '86')
, ('ABC1321', '1', '9/1/2018', '10/31/2018', '2', '1023.36', '511.68', '87')
, ('ABC1322', '1', '7/1/2019', '8/31/2019', '2', '-3772.86', '-1886.43', '88')
, ('ABC1323', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1223.6', '244.72', '89')
, ('ABC1324', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-1058.82', '-151.26', '90')
, ('ABC1325', '1', '1/1/2019', '4/30/2019', '4', '1669.16', '417.29', '91')
, ('ABC1326', '1', '7/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '6', '3031.5', '505.25', '92')
, ('ABC1327', '1', '8/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '5', '2325.1', '465.02', '93')
, ('ABC1328', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1571.22', '224.46', '94')
, ('ABC1329', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '5521.05', '1104.21', '95')
, ('ABC1330', '1', '8/1/2019', '11/30/2019', '4', '26697.68', '6674.42', '96')
, ('ABC1331', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '1254.96', '104.58', '97')
, ('ABC1332', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-1396.71', '-199.53', '98')
, ('ABC1333', '1', '6/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '2', '-1094.16', '-547.08', '99')
, ('ABC1334', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '-1094.16', '-547.08', '100')
, ('ABC1335', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1900.6', '380.12', '101')
, ('ABC1336', '1', '3/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '5', '1013.75', '202.75', '102')
, ('ABC1337', '1', '5/1/2019', '6/30/2019', '2', '-1643.44', '-821.72', '103')
, ('ABC1338', '1', '9/1/2019', '10/31/2019', '2', '-5126.8', '-2563.4', '104')
, ('ABC1339', '1', '1/1/2018', '4/30/2018', '4', '1490.4', '372.6', '105')
, ('ABC1340', '1', '3/1/2018', '4/30/2018', '2', '1005.64', '502.82', '106')
, ('ABC1341', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-191.38', '-27.34', '107')
, ('ABC1342', '1', '2/1/2019', '3/31/2019', '2', '-376.08', '-188.04', '108')
, ('ABC1343', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '647.96', '323.98', '109')
, ('ABC1344', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '38.65', '7.73', '110')
, ('ABC1345', '1', '2/1/2018', '3/31/2018', '2', '1588.16', '794.08', '111')
, ('ABC1346', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '322', '64.4', '112')
, ('ABC1347', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '2396.75', '479.35', '113')
, ('ABC1348', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '1403.52', '701.76', '114')
, ('ABC1349', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '10790.43', '1541.49', '115')
, ('ABC1350', '1', '11/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '2', '437.62', '218.81', '116')
, ('ABC1351', '1', '1/1/2018', '10/31/2018', '10', '2188.1', '218.81', '117')
, ('ABC1352', '1', '1/1/2018', '3/31/2018', '3', '-663.72', '-221.24', '118')
, ('ABC1353', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1043.25', '208.65', '119')
, ('ABC1354', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '287.21', '41.03', '120')
, ('ABC1355', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1979.2', '395.84', '121')
, ('ABC1356', '1', '9/1/2018', '11/30/2018', '3', '2.43', '0.81', '122')
, ('ABC1357', '1', '6/1/2018', '8/31/2018', '3', '2.43', '0.81', '123')
, ('ABC1358', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1167.8', '233.56', '124')
, ('ABC1359', '1', '1/1/2018', '4/30/2018', '4', '-23.36', '-5.84', '125')
, ('ABC1360', '1', '2/1/2018', '3/31/2018', '2', '325.62', '162.81', '126')
, ('ABC1361', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '2151.31', '307.33', '127')
, ('ABC1362', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1770.25', '354.05', '128')
, ('ABC1363', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '2207.66', '315.38', '129')
, ('ABC1364', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '-8469.62', '-4234.81', '130')
, ('ABC1365', '1', '3/1/2019', '4/30/2019', '2', '192.76', '96.38', '131')
, ('ABC1366', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '2217.02', '1108.51', '132')
, ('ABC1367', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-803.1', '-160.62', '133')
, ('ABC1368', '1', '2/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '6', '1203.66', '200.61', '134')
, ('ABC1369', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-732.13', '-104.59', '135')
, ('ABC1370', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-867.25', '-173.45', '136')
, ('ABC1371', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '2616.24', '218.02', '137')
, ('ABC1372', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '819.95', '163.99', '138')
, ('ABC1373', '1', '1/1/2018', '10/31/2018', '10', '1664.7', '166.47', '139')
, ('ABC1374', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '8251.55', '1650.31', '140')
, ('ABC1375', '1', '3/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '3', '1712.97', '570.99', '141')
, ('ABC1376', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '235.06', '117.53', '142')
, ('ABC1377', '1', '8/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '5', '393', '78.6', '143')
, ('ABC1378', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '4555.6', '650.8', '144')
, ('ABC1379', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '3224.15', '644.83', '145')
, ('ABC1380', '1', '1/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '5', '5438.65', '1087.73', '146')
, ('ABC1381', '1', '3/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '5', '1536.65', '307.33', '147')
, ('ABC1382', '1', '5/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '3', '755.46', '251.82', '148')
, ('ABC1383', '1', '8/1/2018', '9/30/2018', '2', '-622.38', '-311.19', '149')
, ('ABC1384', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '2921.1', '584.22', '150')
, ('ABC1385', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-7026.65', '-1405.33', '151')
, ('ABC1386', '1', '1/1/2018', '4/30/2018', '4', '5617.76', '1404.44', '152')
, ('ABC1387', '1', '10/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '3', '1065.48', '355.16', '153')
, ('ABC1388', '1', '5/1/2018', '9/30/2018', '5', '2642.2', '528.44', '154')
, ('ABC1389', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1652.9', '330.58', '155')
, ('ABC1390', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-4544.89', '-649.27', '156')
, ('ABC1391', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '3323', '664.6', '157')
, ('ABC1392', '1', '1/1/2019', '3/31/2019', '3', '-1866.93', '-622.31', '158')
, ('ABC1393', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-3962.28', '-566.04', '159')
, ('ABC1394', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '1253.62', '626.81', '160')
, ('ABC1395', '1', '2/1/2018', '3/31/2018', '2', '-168.06', '-84.03', '161')
, ('ABC1396', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-10632.65', '-1518.95', '162')
, ('ABC1397', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '-387.3', '-193.65', '163')
, ('ABC1398', '1', '1/1/2019', '3/31/2019', '3', '4618.59', '1539.53', '164')
, ('ABC1399', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-4465.93', '-637.99', '165')
, ('ABC1400', '1', '3/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '3', '819.15', '273.05', '166')
, ('ABC1401', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '3840.83', '548.69', '167')
, ('ABC1402', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1059.24', '151.32', '168')
, ('ABC1403', '1', '1/1/2019', '3/31/2019', '3', '2261.64', '753.88', '169')
, ('ABC1404', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '3103.1', '443.3', '170')
, ('ABC1405', '1', '5/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '8', '830.24', '103.78', '171')
, ('ABC1406', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '1210.65', '242.13', '172')
, ('ABC1407', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-6883.3', '-1376.66', '173')
, ('ABC1408', '1', '2/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '4', '-398.36', '-99.59', '174')
, ('ABC1409', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-2524.4', '-504.88', '175')
, ('ABC1410', '1', '5/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '3', '-2734.62', '-911.54', '176')
, ('ABC1411', '1', '4/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '4', '-894.6', '-223.65', '177')
, ('ABC1412', '1', '1/1/2018', '3/31/2018', '3', '325.8', '108.6', '178')
, ('ABC1413', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '871.55', '174.31', '179')
, ('ABC1414', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '880.96', '440.48', '180')
, ('ABC1415', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1989.33', '284.19', '181')
, ('ABC1416', '1', '1/1/2018', '12/31/2018', '12', '19911.84', '1659.32', '182')
, ('ABC1417', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-1193.85', '-170.55', '183')
, ('ABC1418', '1', '1/1/2019', '3/31/2019', '3', '1215.84', '405.28', '184')
, ('ABC1419', '1', '4/1/2018', '5/31/2018', '2', '-2399.12', '-1199.56', '185')
, ('ABC1420', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '521.71', '74.53', '186')
, ('ABC1421', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-867.25', '-173.45', '187')
, ('ABC1422', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '8053.36', '1150.48', '188')
, ('ABC1423', '1', '2/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '6', '1124.76', '187.46', '189')
, ('ABC1424', '1', '1/1/2019', '2/28/2019', '2', '24.2', '12.1', '190')
, ('ABC1425', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '2780.26', '397.18', '191')
, ('ABC1426', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-236.53', '-33.79', '192')
, ('ABC1427', '1', '4/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '2', '1342.9', '671.45', '193')
, ('ABC1428', '1', '7/1/2018', '11/30/2018', '5', '2276.85', '455.37', '194')
, ('ABC1429', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '2096.25', '419.25', '195')
, ('ABC1430', '1', '1/1/2018', '2/28/2018', '2', '317', '158.5', '196')
, ('ABC1431', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-789.9', '-157.98', '197')
, ('ABC1432', '1', '1/1/2019', '5/31/2019', '5', '-4065.65', '-813.13', '198')
, ('ABC1433', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '-1058.82', '-151.26', '199')
, ('ABC1434', '1', '1/1/2018', '7/31/2018', '7', '1148.84', '164.12', '200')



declare @start_date date, @end_date date, @Number varchar(50), @P_Values varchar(50), @Counter int, @id int, @end_id int, @MonthlyAmount money;

set @Counter = 1
select @end_id = max(MultipleMonthid) from #TEST_Data;


    declare @months table (
        id int identity (1,1)
        , Number varchar(50)
        , P_Values varchar(50)
        , month_id int
        , month_start date
        , month_end date
        , MultipleMonthid int
        , MonthlyAmount money
        , primary key (id)
        );

while @Counter <= @end_id
BEGIN
SELECT @start_date = StartDate
        ,@end_date = EndDate
        ,@Number = Number 
        ,@P_Values = P_Values
        ,@id = MultipleMonthid
        ,@MonthlyAmount = MonthlyAmount
        FROM #TEST_Data
        Where MultipleMonthid = @Counter
while @start_date <= @end_date
    begin
        insert into @months (Number, P_Values, month_id, month_start, month_end, MultipleMonthid, MonthlyAmount) 
        values (@Number, @P_Values,left(convert(varchar, @start_date, 112), 6), @start_date, eomonth(@start_date), @id, @MonthlyAmount);
        set @start_date = dateadd(month, 1, @start_date)
    end
set @Counter = @Counter + 1
end
;

select *
from @months
```

Comment: You don't need a cursor for this operation.  But to fix it, you should explain what you are doing.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What kind of SQL are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff The code I included above provides some sample data as well as the desired results.

Comment: @Adam I am currently using SSMS 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest cursor would be straight SQL.(ie by not using a row by row to method to load records, in other words the while loop logic)

Here from the look of the query, you wish to insert as many records as there are between the start_date and end_dates by [Number], Here is how i would do this using straight sql.

```
    declare @months table (
        id int identity (1,1)
        , Number varchar(50)
        , P_Values varchar(50)
        , month_id int
        , month_start date
        , month_end date
        , MultipleMonthid int
        , MonthlyAmount money
        , primary key (id)
        );

with data
  as (--This block would be able to generate 2552 month gaps...
      select row_number() over(order by (select null))-1 as rnk
       from master..spt_values
     )
  insert
    into @months
        ( [Number] 
        , P_Values 
        , month_id 
        , month_start 
        , month_end 
        , MultipleMonthid 
        , MonthlyAmount 
        )
 select td.[Number]
      , td.P_Values
      , left(convert(varchar, dateadd(month,rnk,td.startdate), 112), 6) as month_id 
      , dateadd(month,rnk,td.startdate)          as month_start
      , eomonth(dateadd(month,rnk,td.startdate)) as month_end
      , dense_rank() over(order by td.[Number] ) as multiplemonthid
      , td.monthlyamount                         as MonthlyAmount
   from #TEST_Data td
   join data d
     on dateadd(month,rnk,td.startdate)<=td.EndDate;
     
 
 select *
   from @months;
 --1019 rows..
```

Here is the dbfiddle link which you can make use to verify your results

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=80c1342607f09583c39bf209805d4c3e

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Not only does it improve performance significantly I am able follow the logic you used and learned some along the way. Thank you!